# Rest API made in nodejs-express already in production only accepts optional requests

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

The api is being consumed from a react app with axios

OPTIONAL requests only come when I'm actually consuming POST requests

App.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan');
require('dotenv').config()
const app = express();
const authToken = require("./middlewares/auth_token");
const config = require('./config/config')

//SETTINGS
app.set('port', config.API_PORT ||  4000);


//MIDDLEWARES

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.use(authToken);
app.use('/api/user', require('./routes/user'));
app.use('/api/user/auth', require('./routes/auth'));
app.use('/api/user/profile', require('./routes/profile'));
app.use('/api/user/events', require('./routes/events'));


module.exports = app;
```

index.js

```
const app = require('./app');
require('./database/database');

async function main() {

    await app.listen(app.get('port'));
    console.log(`Server on port ${app.get('port')}`);
}
main();
```

sorry for my english, greetings from Colombia

Comment: What are the exact error messages that the browser is logging in the devtools console?

Comment: The console is empty, but in network:
***************************
General:
Request URL: http://159.89.80.82:4000/api/user/auth/login
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

****************************
Request Headers:
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 47
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Host: 159.89.80.82:4000
Origin: http://159.89.80.82:3000
Referer: http://159.89.80.82:3000/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N)